# Tesseract.js hanging and not giving any feedback after install

Tags: tesseract, tesseract.js

> I tryed to use tesseract.js in a node server so I can do some ocr on
>   some invoices. I did what the docs say regarding the
>   [instalation](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js) but after I
>   tryed the sample code it's like everything is hanging and I don't get
>   any feedback in the console.
>
> Here is what I did
>
> Install

```
npm install --save tesseract.js
```

> Code

```
       Tesseract.recognize(buffer, {
                    lang: 'eng',
                })
                .progress(message => console.log('progress is: ', message))
                .catch(err => {
                    console.error(`\r\n ERROD =>`, err, `\r\n`);
                    reject(err);
                })
                .then(result => {
                    console.log(`\r\n SUCCESS =>`, result, `\r\n`);
                    resolve(result);
                })
                .finally(resultOrError => {
                    console.log(`\r\n FINALLY =>`, resultOrError, `\r\n`);
                });
```

> I don't get any reponse and the console does not print anything. Do I
>   need to install also something else ?  Note I thaught the `tesseract`
>   ocr needs to be installed so I tryed also to do this.

```
brew install tesseract
```

> But still no response from the package, did anyone encounter this ?

```
Node version - 8.11.2
```